# How to get the very last non-list element of a multidimensional list in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want to retrieve the very last element of a multidimensional list, like this:

```
GetLastElement([[2, 3], [2, [3, 4], [5, 6]]]) # Returns 6
GetLastElement([[3, [4]]]) # Returns 4
```

The problem is that I can't find an easy solution, and it affects readability. For example, if I wanted to get the last element, I would use `[...][-1]` instead of defining `Last` and using `Last([...])` repeatedly—until I forget that I'm working on another project that doesn't contain `Last`.

I expect the answers to be non-recursive (meaning, they don't use recursion). Importing is fine for me.

This is what I except the `GetLastElement` function to be

```
def GetLastElement(List_to_get):
    ToReturn = List_to_get
    while True:
        if isinstance(ToReturn, list):
            ToReturn = ToReturn[-1]
        else:
            return ToReturn
```

However, I want to shorten it in one line of code without using `def` or `lambda`.

Comment: Your examples are all arbitrary depth. Your solutions are either packages (pandas, numpy, others) or recursion. There is no one liner without a function involved. Closed as duplicate...